# Assign a Y/N flag based last 12 month activity

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a list of hospital patients and would like to flag each patient account with a "Y" if they were seen in the hospital nine or more times over the past 12 months.

I've come up with this, which would work fine if the patient list were static and only included a 12 month period:

```
SELECT
ENC.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID,
ENC.PAT_MRN_ID,
ENC.ADT_ARRIVAL_DTTM,
case when count(distinct txn.hsp_account_id) over(partition by PAT.PAT_MRN_ID) >= 9 then 'Y' else 'N' end as familiar_face_yn
FROM CLARITY.F_ED_ENCOUNTERS ENC
WHERE ENC.SERVICE_DATE BETWEEN '1-JUL-17' AND '31-OCT-18'
```

But I'd like to query the prior two years worth of data but only use the 12 months prior to the arrival date (ENC.ADT_ARRIVAL_DTTM) in calculating the Y or N.

The problem I'm running in to with the above query is that it's going back and counting all visits by a particular patient between 7/1/17 and 10/31/18.

What I'd like is that if the arrival date for a record is 8/1/18, it should count all visits between 8/1/17 and 8/1/18, ignoring anything with an arrival date earlier than 8/1/17 or later than 8/1/18.

Is this sort of "rolling" calculation possible?  Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add an [MCVE] including an example of your table structure (as a DDL statement) and some sample data (as a DML statement) and your expected output for that sample data. It is often clearer to see what you are talking about with an example as it requires less guessing from us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a windowing clause:

```
SELECT ENC.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID, ENC.PAT_MRN_ID, ENC.ADT_ARRIVAL_DTTM,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT txn.hsp_account_id) OVER
                      (PARTITION BY PAT.PAT_MRN_ID
                       ORDER BY ENC.SERVICE_DATE
                       RANGE BETWEEN 365 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                      ) >= 9 
             THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' 
        END) as familiar_face_yn
FROM CLARITY.F_ED_ENCOUNTERS ENC
WHERE ENC.SERVICE_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2017-07-01' AND DATE '2018-10-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
 (
    SELECT
       ENC.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID,
       ENC.PAT_MRN_ID,
       ENC.ADT_ARRIVAL_DTTM,
       -- find the most recent visit
       max(ENC.ADT_ARRIVAL_DTTM) over(partition by PAT.PAT_MRN_ID) as last_date
    FROM CLARITY.F_ED_ENCOUNTERS ENC
    WHERE ENC.SERVICE_DATE BETWEEN '1-JUL-17' AND '31-OCT-18'
 )
select ...
   -- count all rows with within a 12 month range before the most recent visit
   case when count(distinct case when ADT_ARRIVAL_DTTM >= add_months(last_date, -12) then txn.hsp_account_id end)
             over (partition by PAT.PAT_MRN_ID) >= 9
        then 'Y'
        else 'N' 
   end as familiar_face_yn
from cte
```

I don't know if you really need the DISTINCT count...